# Cannot access files from full RAID5 drives

Tags: raid, qnap

We have a QNAP NAS (TS-869L with firmware 4.2.2, if relevant) where we backup our data. Last night it completely filled up the drives that are in RAID 5 (ext4).

Now I can cd into the directory but I can't ls or rm any files: doing so hangs the terminal indefinitely, and the corresponding process goes in "D" status immediately:

`25709 admin       280 D   /bin/ls -F`

Is there any way I can remove any file to restore functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved by:

- shutting down the NAS, and starting up again (reboot was of no use)
- entering the recycle bin from the web interface
- removing one file from the recycle bin

Anything else I tried failed.